¿cómo resolver resolver errores en código en matlab de interpolacion de Hermite y ejecutar?
he estado tratando de resolver un ejercicio de interpolación de Hermite con matlab pero no logro ejecutarlo, pueden ayudarme con las correcciones? no entiendo por que el código no se ejecuta y me muestra demasiados errores. para el segundo Código, he intentado calcular la cota de error sin ningún éxito.   es el siguiente:
% Definir la función f(x)
f = @(x) 3*x*exp(x) - exp(2*x);

% Definir los puntos conocidos
x0 = 1;
x1 = 1.05;

% Calcular las derivadas de f en los puntos x0 y x1
df_x0 = (3*exp(x0) + 3*x0*exp(x0)) - 2*exp(2*x0);
df_x1 = (3*exp(x1) + 3*x1*exp(x1)) - 2*exp(2*x1);

% Calcular el polinomio interpolante de Hermite de grado 3
syms x;
p = ((1 - 2*(x - x0)*subs(diff((x - x0)^2*(x - x1)^2), x0)) * f(x0) + (x - x0)*subs(diff((x - x0)*(x - x1)^2), x0)*df_x0 + (1 - 2*(x - x1)*subs(diff((x - x0)*(x - x1)^2), x1)) * f(x1) + (x - x1)*subs(diff((x - x0)^2*(x - x1)), x1)*df_x1);

% Aproximación de f(1.03) usando el polinomio interpolante
aproximacion = double(subs(p, 1.03));

% Calcular el error real
valor_exacto = f(1.03);
error_real = abs(valor_exacto - aproximacion);

% Calcular la cota de error
cuarta_derivada = diff(f, 4);
xi = 1.03; % Punto en el que se evalúa la cota de error
cota_error = abs(subs(cuarta_derivada, xi) / (4*factorial(4)) * (xi - 1)*(xi - 1)*(xi - x0)*(xi - x1));

% Mostrar resultados
disp(['Aproximación del polinomio a 1.03: ', num2str(aproximacion)]);
disp(['Error real: ', num2str(error_real)]);
disp(['Cota de error: ', num2str(cota_error)]);

% Graficar el polinomio interpolante
fplot(p, [1, 1.05]);
title('Polinomio interpolante de Hermite de grado 3');
xlabel('x');
ylabel('p(x)');

tambien he intentado con este otro código, el detalle es que este no me muestra la cota de error, no logro entender.
%--------------------------------------------------
function P = HPoly(x,y,yp)
    n = length(x) ;
    for k=1:(2*n)
        Bx(:,k)=x'.^(k-1) ;
    end
    Bp(:,1)=zeros(n,1) ;
    for k=2:(2*n)
        Bp(:,k)=(k-1)*x'.^(k-2) ;
    end
    P = flip([Bx;Bp]\[y,yp]')';
end
%--------------------------------------------------
function y = f(x)
    y = 3*x.*exp(x)-exp(2*x) ;
end
function y = fp(x)
    y = 3*exp(x).*(x + 1) - 2*exp(2*x);
end
%--------------------------------------------------
% GRADO 3
%
x  = [1, 1.05] ;
y  = f(x) ;
yp = fp(x);

xtest = 1.03 ;
%--------------------------------------------------

P = HPoly(x,y,yp) ;
Err3 = polyval(P,xtest) - f(xtest)
function Lagrange_error_bound = max(abs((xtest-x(1))*(xtest-x(2)))*(abs(fp(t))/(2*factorial(3))), abs((xtest-x(1))*(xtest-x(2))*(xtest-x(3)))*(abs(fp(t))/(6*factorial(4))));
  end
xb = [1:.001:1.05];
yb = f(xb) ;
H = polyval(P,xb) ;

subplot(2,2,1);plot(xb,yb,"r",xb,H,"g",x,y,"r*")
subplot(2,2,2);plot(xb,H-yb,xtest,Err3,"r*")

%--------------------------------------------------

% GRADO 5
%
x  = [1, 1.05, 1.07] ;
y  = f(x) ;
yp = fp(x);

xtest = 1.03 ;
%--------------------------------------------------

P = HPoly(x,y,yp) ;
Err5 = polyval(P,xtest) - f(xtest)

xb = [1:.001:1.07];
yb = f(xb) ;
H = polyval(P,xb) ;

subplot(2,2,3);plot(xb,yb,"r",xb,H,"g",x,y,"r*")
subplot(2,2,4);plot(xb,H-yb,xtest,Err5,"r*")
%--------------------------------------------------

necesito calcular la cota de error tanto para el polinomio de grado tres, como para el de grado 5. Espero encontrar ayuda.
